# What is wrong with my initial setup to install ceph?

Tags: centos, ceph

I have downloaded ceph-ansible to install ceph for an evaluation and I ran on an error with package dependencies and I can't find anything about how to fix this using either ceph-ansible or yum.

The error I got using ceph-ansible is below:

```
Tuesday 28 May 2019  14:48:06 -0300 (0:00:00.292)       0:05:17.302 *********** 
FAILED - RETRYING: install ceph-mgr packages on RedHat or SUSE (3 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: install ceph-mgr packages on RedHat or SUSE (2 retries left).
changed: [ceph-mon-02]
changed: [ceph-mon-03]
FAILED - RETRYING: install ceph-mgr packages on RedHat or SUSE (1 retries left).
fatal: [ceph-mon-01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  attempts: 3
  changes:
    installed:
    - ceph-mgr
    - ceph-mgr-dashboard
    - ceph-mgr-diskprediction-local
  msg: |-
    Error: Package: python2-pecan-1.3.2-1.el7.noarch (centos-ceph-nautilus)
               Requires: python2-webob
  rc: 1
  results:
  - |-
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.globo.com
     * centos-ceph-nautilus: mirror.globo.com
     * epel: mirror.globo.com
     * extras: mirror.globo.com
     * updates: mirror.globo.com
    257 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
```

My OS is:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
```

One weird thing is that it seems ceph-ansible ran different operations on ceph-mon-01, ceph-mon-02 and ceph-mon-03, and only ceph-mon-01 had errors.

I already tried to install python-2.7.16 and tried to install packages one by one, by hand, but I can't find packages with "python2-" prefix (python2-pecan, python2-webob) and the required versions.

I haven't found any error for this versions of OS and ceph/ceph-ansible using google and had no replies asking about this error on cephusers email list.

EDIT: I have the exact same problem trying to follow Ceph's installation tutorial using ceph-deploy. I get this error while trying to run:

`yum install ceph-deploy ceph`

Answer (score 1):

I just stuck at "python2-pecan requires python2-webob" too.

```
Error: Package: python2-pecan-1.3.2-1.el7.noarch (centos-ceph-nautilus)
           Requires: python2-webob
```

Checked around for a while.

For example, I found webob is installed, but "Requires: python2-webob" error still happen.

In the end, I destroyed my vm and edited ceph.repo, and cp to /etc/yum.repos.d.

(as instructed by ceph doc : https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/install/get-packages/)

And I was able to install ceph (ceph-mgr in particular) and started monitor, mgr, osd.

I guess this has something to do with package priorities.

Best Regard,
JimmyYS

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The only way I managed to install it on CentOS 7 was to install Mimic and then, once it was running correctly, update to Nautilus.